# Verb for meeting the requirements of a policy

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I'm looking for a verb that would go with *policy*.

Our company has a policy, which defines a set of requirements. I want to say that I am responsible for ensuring that the company meets the requirements of the policy, but I don't really want to use the word *requirements*. Is there a word that I could use like this:

> I am responsible for [some verb] the policy.

Comment: enforcement of...?

Comment: @SF. No. See answers below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps, *comply*?

> I am responsible for *complying with* the policy.

If only transitive verbs are allowed, then:

> I am responsible for *meeting/fulfilling* the policy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The second example sounds perfect.

Comment: I think a passive sense sounds more natural, like "I am responsible for ensuring the policy is complied with."

Comment: *Implementing* is also common here, although it could be taken to mean *enacting*.

Comment: I don't think "I am responsible for complying with the policy." meets what the OP wants. He bears the responsibility for making sure the _company_ complies with the policy; he does not himself have to comply with the policy.

Comment: @GarrettAlbright You have a good point.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I see your point. The person responsible for a task isn't necessarily the same as the people executing the task, especially in the context of a large organization with division of labor.

Answer (score 6):

> I am responsible for **enforcing** the policy.

Comment: That would mean I am responsible for other people meeting the requirements. What I want to say, though, is that I make adjustments to whatever the company does, to make sure we meet the requirements. But thanks anyway!

Comment: I think Jasper's answer is based on a certain ambiguity in the question. Now that the OP has explained it, I would recommend: *I am responsible for ensuring that the policy is complied with.*

Answer (score 2):

> I am responsible for the **adherence** to the policy.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to write adherence **to** the policy? Adherence **of** the policy does not seem to make much sense.

Comment: @DilipSarwate - Correct. Adherence is a noun.  Now corrected.

Answer (score 2):

> I am responsible for ensuring that the company complies with the policy.

In some cases, people like you would be referred to as Compliance Officers.