# Word that means "one out of a series must be true"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am trying to come up with a word or phrase that means "one out of a series must be true".

**Example #1**:

I have a list of roles that a user can belong to.  What is a word that describes a list of roles where the user may belong to one of them?  They could belong to more than one.

**Example #2**:

There is a list of requirements to be eligible for a prize.  You may meet multiple requirements, but you only need to meet one requirement to be eligible.

Sentence example:  The following roles are `_______`.

The best that I can come up with is "required roles", but, that seems funky to me as not all of the roles are required.

Comment: I'd like to make a request: How would you use this word in a sentence? (You can insert a `_______` where you would put the word you're trying to find.)

Comment: @J.R., can you clarify what goes in the blank in your comment?  Are you asking Ek0nomik to specify part-of-speech, via a term like noun, adjective, etc.?

Comment: @jwpat: I'm just trying to get a better idea of how the word would be used. (I think I could probably derive the part-of-speech from the sentence). As an example, I think the O.P. of [#71317](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71317) did a good job on this; I thought something similar here could be helpful for everyone.

Comment: @J.R. - I just edited my answer; hopefully it adds a little more context.

Comment: @J.R., ok, I misunderstood what you wrote – I thought you wanted Ek0nomik to fill in the blank in your parenthesized sentence, when instead you were suggesting he or she use those characters to represent a blank.  :)

Comment: Your second example is unclear. Do you perhaps mean *"You may meet multiple requirements, but you only **need** to meet one requirement to be eligible"*?

Comment: @Ek0nomik To clarify: by "[funky](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/funky)", do you mean *malodorous*, *passionate*, *terrified*, *authentic*, or *cool*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would generally address your first case is by looking at it one level of abstraction up: a *role* is required, and the role may be any one of the list of possible cases.

You could possibly say about your second case that each requirement is **sufficient** (as in [the concepts of sufficiency and necessity in logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency)).  Having a bunch of sufficient conditions implies that you have to have at least one of them, otherwise there are zero sufficient conditions and the statement fails.

I wouldn't use that term in user interface, but it may be helpful for internal nomenclature.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer since your mention of sufficient versus necessity got me down the right path.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Ek0nomik: What solution did you end up using?

Comment: It was essentially a programming name question, but I feel like there just isn't a great set of names to use.  I ended up using _SufficientRoles_ and _MandatoryRoles_.  Basically I have two sets of roles.  Every role in _MandatoryRoles_ must be met, while the user only needs to be in at least one role of the _SufficientRoles_.  I've never had such a hard time naming something.

Answer (score 2):

Example 1 isn't quite the same as Example 2, to my mind:

I'd state the former as 'One of the following roles is *mandatory*.' The second one can be stated as : 'All these roles are *prizewinning.*' Or 'Any one of the following roles *qualify you for a prize*.'

Answer (score 1):

If the user can belong to only one, the roles are *mutually exclusive* because belonging to any one excludes membership of all the others.

I'm not entirely sure that "Mutually inclusive" describes roles the user must belong to; "compulsory roles" might be better.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  The user could belong to more than one, so mutually exclusive wouldn't work.  I like your "compulsory roles" suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

In computer user interfaces, I think it's common to say "required field" for anything where the user must make SOME selection. This is most often applied to text entry, to indicate that you cannot leave it blank, but it also often used for multiple-choice lists.

If you're afraid of ambiguity, you could always say "Role (choose at least one)".

I can't think of a commonly-used word that means "you must select at least one from the following list". If someone else here thinks of such a word, I'll be happy to upvote you. :-) If there's an obscure word, it probably doesn't do you much good, as by definition that means most of your users wouldn't know what it means. I'd rather use four common words that people understand than one obscure word that no one understands.

Comment: +1 for your last two sentences. I can't tell you how many times I've had that same thought when mulling over «single-word-request» questions (particularly after an answer gets downvoted, with the comment "but that isn't just one word.")

Comment: Now that the question has been edited out of all recognition, this is the best answer (so far!). I'd add "must" though: "Role (you must choose at least one)".

Answer (score 1):

I see a problem with OP's "sentence example" *The following roles are ------*, because that would imply the target word somehow describes each role. But what OP actually seeks is a word describing the ***list***.

The first list is an [exhaustive list](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/exhaustive), meaning that it contains all possible roles.

If it's only possible to choose *one* role from the list, it contains [mutually exclusive](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=mutually%20exclusive) options.

If it's *necessary for every user to choose a role*, this would normally be described as a *mandatory* or *compulsory* choice. But note that this description applies to *the act of making a choice*, not to the list as a whole, or any individual roles within it.

The second example is somewhat different - it's not actually *mandatory* that the user should meet *any* of the requirements (he just won't be eligible for a prize if he doesn't). I would describe this situation by saying he must meet *at least one* of the [eligibility criteria](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&newwindow=1&q=eligibility+criteria&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=ENLoT-a0DMXU8QOIwOnTCg&ved=0CFQQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=1821ba54f6c138b6&biw=1538&bih=843) to have a chance of winning.

Comment: Why has this answer been downvoted without even the courtesy of adding a comment? I think it's a valid point... +1 from me simply to compensate the downvote.

Comment: @aaamos: That's very noble-spirited of you, thanks. [Here's](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72403/ponder-about-or-just-ponder/72441#72441) another mystery downvote if you're minded to go crusading on my behalf!

Comment: Heh, given that _that_ answer has >0 votes _and_ has been accepted, I don't think you need my help there ;-) (Or here, for that matter, but it's a matter of principle.) Incidentally, I've been unable to resist upvoting @chaos' answer for the same reason.

Comment: @aaamos: You're right - I don't really need to go courting the "sympathy vote" here on ELU. But I do just get a bit niggled by cases like these, where I can't even come up with a possible *reason* for the downvote. I've just upvoted chaos's answer myself, because *sufficient* could be a useful word in this context - ["both necessary and sufficient"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22both+necessary+and+sufficient%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is a well-worn phrase.

Answer (score 1):

It's a list of *alternatives*? (Or *non-exclusive alternatives*?)

The user should pick a *nonempty subset*.

(Logically, it's a *disjunction*. I.e., there's an OR between all of the roles.)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why no single answer seems to fit your question perfectly is, as @FumbleFingers points out, because there is some confusion about whether the word or phrase should apply to *each criterion* or to *the list of criteria*.

I would, in fact, stipulate that what you're looking for relates to the *relationship* between each criterion and the list of criteria, which makes this difficult, because a word or phrase describing either one (but not both) is insufficient.

Sometimes, the answer is already embedded in the question - what's wrong with simply saying: "One of the following roles is compulsory/required"?